# How to get a secrets "file" into Google Cloud Build so docker compose can read it?

Tags: docker-compose, google-cloud-build

How can I configure Google Cloud Build so that a docker-compose setup can use a secret file the same way as it does when it is run locally on my machine accessing a file?

My Docker-compose based setup uses a `secrets` entry to expose an API key to a backend component like this (simplified for example):

```
services:
  backend:
    build: docker_contexts/backend
    secrets:
      - API_KEY
    environment:
      - API_KEY_PATH=/run/secrets/api_key

secrets:
  API_KEY:
    file: ./secrets/api_key.json
```

From my understanding `docker-compose` places any files in the `secrets` section in `/run/secrets` on the local container for access, that's why the target location is hard-coded to `/run/build`.

I would like to deploy my docker-compose setup on Google Cloud Build to use this configuration, but the only examples I've seen in documentation have been to load the secret as an environment variable. I have tried to provide this secret to the secret manager and copy it to a local file at `/run/secrets` like this:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  # copy to /workspace/secrets so docker-compose can find it
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: [ '-c', 'echo $API_KEY > /workspace/secrets/api_key.json' ]
  volumes:
  - name: 'secrets'
    path: /workspace/secrets
  secretEnv: ['API_KEY']
# running docker-compose
- name: 'docker/compose:1.29.2'
  args: ['up', '-d']
  volumes:
  - name: 'secrets'
    path: /workspace/secrets

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/ID/secrets/API_KEY/versions/1
      env: API_KEY
```

But when I run the job on google cloud build, I get this error message after everything is built: `ERROR: for backend  Cannot create container for service backend: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /workspace/secrets/api_key.json`.

Is there a way I can copy the `API_KEY` environment variable at the `cloudbuild.yaml` level so it is accessible to the `docker-compose` level like it is when I run it on my local filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the value of `API_KEY` taken from Secret Manager and placed into a text file at `/workspace/secrets/api_key.json` then change your step to this:

```yaml
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args: ["-c", "mkdir -p /workspace/secrets && echo $$API_KEY > /workspace/secrets/api_key.json"]
    secretEnv: ["API_KEY"]
```

This will:

1. Remove the unnecessary [`volumes` attribute](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema) which is not necessary as `/workspace` is *already* a volume that persists between steps
2. Make sure the directory exists before you try to put a file in it
3. Use the `$$` syntax as described in [Use secrets from Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#access-utf8-secrets) so that it echoes the actual secret to the file

Note this section:

> When specifying the secret in the args field, specify it using the environment variable prefixed with `$$`.

You can double-check that this is working by adding another step:

```yaml
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args: ["-c", "cat /workspace/secrets/api_key.json"]
```

This should echo out the contents of the file as the build step, allowing you to confirm that:

1. The previous step read the secret
2. The previous step wrote the secret to the file
3. The file was written to a volume that persists across steps

From there you can configure docker-compose to read the contents of that persisted file.